# .Net Framework 1.1 on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7-64 bit)

Tags: .net, windows-7, iis-7.5, .net-1.1, worker-process

I'm in a situation where i will need to get my .Net 1.1 codebase setup in Windows 7, 64 bit machine that has IIS 7.5.

I tried all possible blog posts including:
[.NET Framework 1.1 on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502081/net-framework-1-1-on-iis-7), 
[using dot net 1.1 on IIS 7.5 (windows 7 - 32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940082/using-dot-net-1-1-on-iis-7-5-windows-7-32-bit),
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx

and a lot many out of google search.  But nothing worked.  Am I doing something wrong here?

I installed framework correctly, had a couple of reboot too as prompted.  But .Net Framework 1.1 is not listed as an option in the drop down at all.

**Here is the screen shot.**

[image]

**First part:** ISAPI and CGI restrictions: shows up the dll correctly.
**Second part:** Even in the app pool, ASP.NET 1.1 got created with the steps i followed but the framework version selection doesn't contain 1.1

**Here is the screen shot of my %windir%**

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

***Update***

I could setup the code base but this is a new problem now.  While trying to debug from VS 2010, getting the below message. Any idea?

IDE: VS 2010 Professional

IIS: 7.5

[image]

OK.  After a long struggle, I installed VS 2010 on my old XP machine and re-built the application there itself and then moved the source code back to Windows 7.  No Framework 1.1 anymore.  It's now mapped to 4.0 (VS project conversion)

Installed Debug Diag and that resulted in this message finally.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure an ASP.NET 1.1 web application will run on ASP.NET 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: Thanks Jrummell for the comment.  I tried creating a sample html page and hosted that under an App Pool.  I got the error "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error: Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" failed" while trying to browse.  Checked all ISAPI/CGI settings and it all fine.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Is it feasible to recompile under .NET 2 or 4?

Comment: FYI: Also the reason why I want to run 1.1 App in 1.1 itself is, there are few event triggers (in code behind) that are not happening when i change the framework version.

Comment: First of all, I'm unable to open the project in VS 2003.  Getting the error message "The web server reported the following error when attempting to create or open the web project located at the following URL:
'http://localhost/TestWebApp'. 'A Connection with the server could not be established'" while trying to open.  All associated C# class library projects are loaded fine.

Comment: Hmm... odd; one of your references is what I used to install 1.1 on my IIS7.5 installation, and mine went without a hitch. :(

Comment: Happy for you Andrew :) This is now driving me nuts :( I'm really going Code"MAD"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the steps as described in the article http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-install-net-framework-11-in-windows-7-64/eb1e6232-e874-432e-ab43-17660e25e43d

Update: I have just tried the steps mentioned in the article and It successfully installed .NET Framework 1.1. As you can see in the image There is already an ASP.NET v1.1 app pool created. But you are right I am not getting the .NET Framework v1.1 in the drop down list when creating new application pool (I think it is because with .NET framework 1.1, the integrated pipeline mode was not available at all)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tariqulazam for the input but no fruit.  I tried this already.  Also verified each and every step to make sure i'm not doing wrong.  No fruit.

Comment: I have updated my post with a bit more detail, see if it helps.

Comment: +1 for showing up interest towards the problem.  But unfortunately, not of any help! :(

Comment: Can you please try the suggestion on this post
http://www.uhleeka.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-install-asp-net-v1-1-with-iis7-on-windows-2008-x64/
I will give it a try and update the post if it is successful.

Comment: That really helped indeed but still the problem persists.  I'm doing some circus with that.  Let me keep you updated with findings if any :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the classic .net app pool to allow 32 bit (in advanced settings) your .net 1.1 apps will run (once 1.1 is installed of course). This is despite .net 1.1 not showing up at all in the dropdowns in the application pools.

I have .net 1.1 with IIS 7.5, and this was how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see the question is old now but would like to put my answer may be of help to someone else.

ASP.Net 1.1 is not  compatible with IIS 7.5

You need to install .net Framework 1.1 service pack 1 and ASp.net Security update for .Net framework 1.1.

After doing this you can see this blog and follow the steps mentioned.

http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/ivorb/archive/2010/07/15/installing-net-1-1-applications-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the MKLINK
MKLINK /d c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v1.1.4322 c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322

this solution work for me and here it explain why.
http://www.uhleeka.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-install-asp-net-v1-1-with-iis7-on-windows-2008-x64/