# Error while hosting .NET 1.1 application on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I am hosting a .NET 1.1 application on IIS7 while browsing my application i am getting an error in application event logs.

> Failed to execute request because the App-Domain could not be created.
>   Error: 0x80131522

Event ID : 1088

Source : ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0

I'm running windows server 2008 Enterprise.  I don't know why error is thown from .NET 2.0 while application is hosted on .NET 1.1.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kennymaita/2011/03/21/using-asp-net-1-1-in-iis7-or-iis7-5/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502081/net-framework-1-1-on-iis-7

Comment: .NET Framework 1.1 is long dead.